# Ansible: How to filter down strings stored in a varriable based on keywords

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am trying to look up the un used disks using ansible. So far I am able to save the unused disk paths in a variable. But I am getting a lot of other useless information such as plus signs and brackets. I was wondering how can I filter the list down and get the strings that include /dev.
This is the code I have so far:

```
- set_fact:
    list_of_disks: []

- name: getting list of disks
  set_fact:
    list_of_disks: "[{{list_of_disks}} + '/dev/{{item.key}}']"
  when:
    - not item.value.partitions
    - not item.value.holders
    - not item.value.links.ids
    - item.key | search ("sd")
  with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"

- name: display unused disks
  debug:
    var: list_of_disks.split("'")
```

And this is the output I am getting

```
    "list_of_disks.split(\"'\")": [
    "[[[] + ",
    "/dev/sde",
    "] + ",
    "/dev/sdc",
    "]"
]
```

}

I would like the output to look like 
"/dev/sde",
"/dev/sdc",

Note: the disk names would change from one server to another. So I don't want to look for sde and sdc only. It should be able to filer down all disks that come up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, might not be exactly the format you want, but:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.device }}"
    with_items: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
    when: "'/dev/' in item.device"
```

Should do the trick.

On my local, I got:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "/dev/mapper/fedora-root"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "/dev/nvme0n1p1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "/dev/mapper/fedora-home"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need them all on one line, then create a variable and append to it:

```
  - set_fact:
      list_of_disks=""

  - set_fact: 
      list_of_disks: "{{ list_of_disks | regex_replace('^, ','') }}, {{ item.device }}"
    with_items: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
    when: "'/dev/' in item.device"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ list_of_disks }}"
```

For this, I got:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/dev/mapper/fedora-root, /dev/nvme0n1p1, /dev/mapper/fedora-home"
}
```